# How to restrict access to property bag values in sharepoint online before loading

Tags: sharepoint-online, property-bag, sppropertybag

I need to restrict specific users to read/update property bag values in SharePoint Online web part.

Only few users should have get/set permissions.

Any references or leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is when you build your web part, you may give the second time verification. Like, set a whitelisted group inside of your code. There is calling APIs when you create a web part, so you can try to give the validate the user ID if he/she can access the web part.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried that too. It blocks the user to see web part in UI but the user can see the data in F12[dev tools].